# Binding Shift+Arrow Key in tmux for use in virtual terminals (tty3-12) (works in X)

Tags: tmux, tty

I've bound Shift+Up/Down/Left/Right to changing selected pane in tmux, but on running tmux in a virtual terminal like tty3, the binding does nothing (and pressing S-Up/S-Down just cycle the command history, like pressing Up/Down alone) - how could I make it work there?

Changing pane with the default bindings (C-b + Up/Down/Left/Right) works.
No characters are printed either on inputting the S-Up/S-Down/S-Left/S-Right shortcuts.

Running tty in a tmux pane returns `/dev/pts/{number}`, I get the same result in tmux in some emulator on X.

Comment: According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244825/459667, these might be indistinguishable from non-modified arrow keys like I've observed. However, the utility `showkey` can detect it (individual keypresses). Is there an option for tmux to interpret the keypresses (instead of characters sent) the same way that `showkey` does?